# Where is the ideal place for django's template?

Tags: django-templates

According to Brian's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891884/where-to-put-a-django-templates-dependent-files/1891905#1891905), he recomends put template dir on the top level django project. In other responses find that every app should have its own template folder.

I wonder if there is an official recommendation or criteria as the peps in python, for the location of the template folder regardless of how many applications may have a django project

Answer (score 0):

App-specific resources belong with the app. Project-wide resources or project-overridden resources belong with the project.